# I installed latest Node JS and I am trying to setup Angular environment but I got the following issue

Tags: angular-cli

[Angular Environment setup issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LEYcq.png)

I installed latest Node JS and I am trying to setup Angular environment.

Answer (score 0):

The phrasing here may be what is confusing you.

The error is correct in that the version of node you are using is incompatible, but actually you need to roll back to an earlier version. As R. Richards said, the message is very clear. Roll back to an earlier node version and the error will be resolved.

Although later versions may not be officially supported, I can confirm that the current LTS version of node (14.17.0) is compatible with the latest stable release of Angular.

P.S. you should include a description of your error, steps required to replicate the error and attempted solutions in your question rather than just a screenshot. You may find that you answer your own question in the process.